# Diffrence between opening excel file path with or without quotas

Tags: excel, citrix

I got a recent problem with Excel.

We are working with macros and it is in a Citrix envoirment.

We are filling an Excel sheet with data that works perfectly fine.
But our coworkers have made themself templates which are getting filled.

Now if you choose the template to be filled it is first pretty slow and then actually freezes/crashes.
What I have recognized when you choose the template like \server\folder\template.xls it crashes but if you choose it like "\server\folder\template.xls" it doesnt but the templates seem not to work as their saved macros won't run.

But what else diffrences between those two Options.
Is it really only macros?

Comment: Most of the time double quote is used, because the folder name contain space (Path with space is difficult to understand for programs, It is better to keep the path with out space). I recommend to use double quote.

Comment: From my opinion i would keep them aswell.
But the coworkers are pretty dependent on those macros they made.
Which is actually bad anyways but i cant do anything about it

Comment: Instruct coworker to debug the macro line by line using `F8` key, and AddWatch. There will always be a small issue which troubles a lot (I have also suffered most of the times),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, we had a problem with the excel Installtion.

There was a problem between Excel 2016 32bit, Excel 2016 64bit and Excel 365.

We made a new clear installation with excel 365 and it worked again.

Therefore still thank you for your help and Ideas.